# (Autohotkey) Problem concerning GUI vertical progress bar not moving vertically(up and down) but horizontally as it does at horizontal Progresbar

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

As the title says, I encountered unexpected matter which is strange.

I am writing the code below to make many progress bars on the screen. The important thing is I want it to move from up to down and vice versa. But even though these ones are looking like vertical bar, it's not moving vertically. It progresses from left to right. I want to make it move from bottom to the top.

Hope anybody know the answer. Thanks

```
;Gui, Add, Button,x-20 y-20 gButton +default
Gui -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
Gui, Margin, 0, 0
Gui, Font,s17 바탕 cBlack


Loop,114
{
    AIndex:=A_Index-1
    X:=Mod(AIndex,30)*40+20
    Y:=(Floor(AIndex/30))*130+30
    Gui,Add,Progress,x%X% y%y% h100 w25 cBlue vMyProgress_%A_Index%,50
    GuiControl,,MyProgress horizontal
}
Mask := "42f442"

Gui,Color, %Mask%
WinSet, TransColor, %Mask%
Gui,-dpiscale 
Gui,Show, x0 y0
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that it's a `vertical` progress bar, like so

```
Gui,Add,Progress,x%X% y%y% h100 w25   Vertical   cBlue vMyProgress_%A_Index%,50
```

[More about progress options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Progress_Options)

Comment: @ggo Glad I could help! :-)